# Change in source schema while loading file data into database, how to handle?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to design a simple data pipeline, like file in S3 is loaded incrementally into a table in postgreSQL table. Logic for loading data, might be a simple copy command, or a python script to import csv into dataframe and load or an aws glue job, whatever.
Everyday at some specific time, the data pipeline is executed and data is loaded from that csv file into the database table.
What if on some particular day, due to some source system issue or whatever, an extra column comes in the csv file? How do I handle this?

If it is a drop table and load logic, I think i can extract column names and dynamically created table with the column names matching.
But this is an incremental load.
Want to explore different approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not just check for extra columns before loading? If you know the schema, you should know what columns are required.

Comment: An alternative approach is to save the data as a JSON Lines (rather than CSV), which allows any key/value combinations. It is slower to query, but is automatically expandable to match your data requirements. Or even Parquet, which includes the schema within the file.

Comment: Third-party tools like Fivetran and Stitch specialize in the ability to detect new columns of incoming data and can create additional columns in the target database. If you're writing the loading function yourself, then you'll need to do similar -- check the column names, compare it against the database schema to find new ones, infer the column type by looking at the supplied data, call the database to add a new column, then load the data. Or, just tell people not to change the CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

A common data warehousing solution is to store incoming rows in a staging table as JSON objects where one column contains the row of data as a JSON object and another column contains a unique key. Additional rows might include metadata about the row such as source and the timestamp of when the row was received.

A query would then be run against the staging table to recreate the columns with column names and type casting. This query could then introduce various quality checks.

This way you can have a setup where your down-stream systems will not break if a column is added or removed as the data lands as JSON and then read quality checked.